# AWS S3 document meta data is exceeding limit for user bearer token

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, file-upload, jwt, bearer-token

I am attaching user bearer token as metadata to the AWS S3 document and generate pre-signed url. So when the user request document from application it cross-check via this token to see if there is no security breach.

Issue occurs when the size of token increases from 2kb. Because AWS don't allow more than 2kb in metadata.

How can I secure the document if I can't use this token as in metadata because of the size limitations

Comment: you could reference a document containing this token in the meta data and then use a lambda function to serve the presigned url, which before serving validates the token

Comment: I don't get your point, what do you mean  by referencing a document containing this token?

Comment: give me a sec i write it in an answer, if it doesnt help you i can delete it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Ok your problem is that your Bearer Token is to large for the meta data of your documents, therefor i suggest to store the BearerToken as an extra document.

The general Structure would be something like this:

```
s3:\\data-bucket\[S3 Object for the User]

s3:\\verification-bucket\[BearerTokenDocument]
```

Now when you create the object which the user can consume, you add the name of the `[BearerTokenDocument]` as Meta Data to the Object.

In your code which you use to serve the document, you do the following:

1. Load the `[S3 Object for the User]`
2. Read the  Meta Data Field which contains the name of the `[BearerTokenDocument]`
3. Load the `[BearerTokenDocument]` and Validate its content
4. Depending on the ValidationResult return a 403 or the `[S3 Object for the User]`

Since your metadata only needs the name of the document and you know where you stored it, the amount of data stored in the MetaData is significant lower then the amount stored in the `[BearerTokenDocument]`

Comment: I understand. but this will add more complexity to the logic as we have millions of users with trillion of documents and it will add a workload and also extra space storage in S3.
What I am looking for is other crypto secure token options other than bearertoken to be used.

Comment: Ahh ok, i would suggest closing the question and respecifiing this. Because i cant really get this info from your question.